# working with a dictionary and web scraping using Python (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python

Mi goal is to obtain a dictionary where the keys would be the variety of genre of movies listed on the page of the url and the values would be movies itself.

I have two things I would like to do. At first i would like to finish the list of genre when it appears the option 'Western', that's why i set this if-condition.
Besides i would like to get a list of movies for each gender instead of receiving None.

Thanks beforehand.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_movies_by_genre = "https://www.imdb.com/feature/genre/?ref_=nv_ch_gr"
req2 = requests.get(url_movies_by_genre, timeout=4) 
source_movies_genre = req2.text 

html2 = BeautifulSoup(source_movies_genre,"html") 

dict_movies_by_genre = dict()
for each in html2.findAll('div',class_= 'table-cell primary'):
    dict_movies_by_genre[each.find('a').text.strip()] = each.get('href')
    if dict_movies_by_genre[each.find('a').text.strip()] == 'Western':
        break
print(dict_movies_by_genre)
```

The output of my code is this:

```
{' Action ': None, ' Adventure ': None, ' Animation ': None, ' Biography ': None, ' Comedy ': None, ' Crime ': None, ' Documentary ': None, ' Drama ': None, ' Family ': None, ' Fantasy ': None, ' Film Noir ': None, ' History ': None, ' Horror ': None, ' Music ': None, ' Musical ': None, ' Mystery ': None, ' Romance ': None, ' Sci-Fi ': None, ' Short Film ': None, ' Sport ': None, ' Superhero ': None, ' Thriller ': None, ' War ': None, ' Western ': None, ' Game Show ': None, ' News ': None, ' Reality-TV ': None, ' Talk Show ': None, ' Reality TV ': None, ' Sports ': None, ' Anime ': None, ' Avant-Garde ': None, ' B-Movie ': None, ' Chick Flick ': None, ' Coming of Age ': None, ' Cult Film ': None, ' Dystopia ': None, ' Epic ': None, ' Espionage ': None, ' Femme Fatale ': None, ' High School ': None, ' Kung Fu ': None, ' Mockumentary ': None, ' Post-Apocalypse ': None, ' Spoof ': None, ' Supernatural ': None, ' Time Travel ': None, ' Vampire ': None, ' Zombie ': None, ' Browse/Search by keyword ': None, ' Most Popular Movies ': None, ' Top Rated Movies ': None, ' Top Rated Indian Movies ': None, ' Most Popular Future Movies ': None, ' Most Popular TV ': None, ' Top Rated TV ': None, ' Most Popular Future TV ': None, ' Short ': None}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is simple that the link is inside a subtag `a`

```
>>> f=html.findAll("div",class_= 'table-cell primary')
>>> t=f[0]
>>> t
<div class="table-cell primary"> <a href="/search/title?genres=action&amp;title_type=feature&amp;explore=genres&amp;pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&amp;pf_rd_p=facfbd0c-6f3d-4c05-9348-22eebd58852e&amp;pf_rd_r=0VC6V2KNET2SN99AHTN1&amp;pf_rd_s=center-6&amp;pf_rd_t=15051&amp;pf_rd_i=genre&amp;ref_=ft_gnr_mvpop_1"> Action </a> </div>
>>> t.a
<a href="/search/title?genres=action&amp;title_type=feature&amp;explore=genres&amp;pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&amp;pf_rd_p=facfbd0c-6f3d-4c05-9348-22eebd58852e&amp;pf_rd_r=0VC6V2KNET2SN99AHTN1&amp;pf_rd_s=center-6&amp;pf_rd_t=15051&amp;pf_rd_i=genre&amp;ref_=ft_gnr_mvpop_1"> Action </a>

>>> t.a.get("href")
'/search/title?genres=action&title_type=feature&explore=genres&pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=facfbd0c-6f3d-4c05-9348-22eebd58852e&pf_rd_r=0VC6V2KNET2SN99AHTN1&pf_rd_s=center-6&pf_rd_t=15051&pf_rd_i=genre&ref_=ft_gnr_mvpop_1'
>>>
```

just change `each.get('href')` for `each.a.get('href')` and that should solve the problem...

For the other issue you mention, is simple, just change the order, do the check first

```
for each in html2.findAll('div',class_= 'table-cell primary'):
    genre = each.find('a').text.strip() #so you don't do the same twice
    if genre == 'Western':
        break
    dict_movies_by_genre[genre] = each.a.get('href')
print(dict_movies_by_genre)
```

Comment: mmm yep i get the links now, but how to get the list of movies inside the link instead?

Comment: you need to go to that link and extract them, just like your doing for the genres, and I recommend putting that into a function...

Comment: Okay. I'll try then. And for my last problem, as i don't want to get the following keys from "Western", any idea on how to fix it? I thought that will be solved once i put the if-condition, but doesn't seem to work

Comment: just change the order, do the check first